# How can I create an Simple API in C# that receives a string and returns a value based on inside logic?

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am a beginner in ASP.NET Core and I want to create a parsing api. Let's say I already have a NuGet that parses a string to an object in the format I want.

Now I only want to create an API that receives the string and returns the parsed object without stuff like database or anything. How could I do that?

I have installed the NuGet in the new WebAPI project and created a ParserController. Should I create just a post method that returns the parsed object? And can I return any object or it has to be json in order to React understand it?

(I'm using ASP.NET Core 5)

Comment: Did you try any of these approaches? Did it work? What issue did you face?

Comment: What you are describing is the very gist of what API controllers can do. You need to start looking up examples of creating API controllers in ASP.NET Core. There are limitless examples and tutorials online.

Comment: Where exactly are you getting stuck? Creating the API method? Psrsing the string to the obect? Returning the object. Start by creating an empty api that takes the string and returns an empty object. Then fill in the blanks with your nuget package. Ask questions here about **specific** problems you have along the way. In the mean time take the [tour] and read the help to get more info on what makes a Stack Overflow question

Answer (score 2):

Basically you create POST method to actually insert something into DB or has to post some json object.

```
// POST: api/Parser
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult<Item> Parse(Item item)
{
    // do something with 'item'
    return item
}
```

If you are passing a string you can use GET with id, for example with abcd:

```
// GET: api/Parser/abcd
[HttpGet("{value}")]
public <ActionResult<string>> GetItemId(string value)
{
    // do something with 'value'

    return value;
}
```

You can return any object or datatype, React can handle the response. If you return a string React will receive it as string, if you return an Object, the response will be a json with members in object, where the keys can be modified, removed etc. as well. This happens both ways as the json binding happens using JsonProperty.

```
public class Videogame
{
    [JsonProperty("something")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("another_thing")]
    public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
}
```

Hope this helps. If you can provide more information, I am more than happy to help and will update my answer accordingly.